# Dimension (manifold) of matrices with exact $r$ positive and $r$ negative eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, smooth-manifolds, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues, hermitian

For the vector space $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$ of $n\times n$ matrices we know that the subset

$$M_{2r}:= \{A\in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C}) \mid \mbox{rank} (A) = 2r \}$$

is a manifold of dimension $2n(2r)-(2r)^2$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518202/what-is-the-codimension-of-matrices-of-rank-r-as-a-manifold)).

If I now take a look at Hermitian $n \times n$ matrices of rank $2r$ with exactly $r$ positive and $r$ negative eigenvalues, how can I determine the dimension of this manifold?

Comment: Why should the dimension be any different? This partitions the manifold of dimension $2n(2r) - (2r)^2$ into a finite number (15) of submanifolds.

Comment: I thougth that the restriction of $r$ postivie and $r$ negative eigenvalues reduces the dimension. I don't got your point in total. Could you explain it with a few more words?

Comment: Given a Hermitian matrix with $r$ positive and $r$ negative eigenvalues, any sufficiently close Hermitian matrix of rank $2r$ will also have $r$ positive and $r$ negative eigenvalues.  On the other hand, the restriction to Hermitian matrices does change the dimension.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Oops. I completely missed the Hermitian requirement.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Is it clear how it would change the dimension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Hermitian matrix of rank $r$ can be represented uniquely as $U D U^\ast,$ where $U$ is an $n\times r$ matrix with orthogonal rows of unit length, and $D$ is an $r\times r$ matrix (this is the singular value decomposition, if you want to think of it that way). The (complex) dimension of the space of $U$ is $n-1 + n-2 + \dotsc+ n-r$ the (real) dimension of the space of $D$s is $r$, for a total of 
$$(2n -r -1)r + r = 2n r - r^2$$ real dimensions, near as I can tell.

Comment: This is a nice simple approach, but it's not exactly what the OP is asking. Also, I'm not sure I agree with the dimension count of the $U$'s, for example the unit vectors (or $n\times 1$ matrices $U$ as above) have real dimension $2n-1$, not $2n-2$.

Comment: But this is has the same dimension like in the case of $M_{2r}$? Could this be since we did not assume that the matricies in $M_{2r}$ are hermitian.

Comment: @IgorRivin : Look at the example $n=3$ and $r=2$ then your formula results in a dimension of $2nr-r^2 = 8$ but the space of symmetric matricies is only of dimension $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=6$? Since the manifold is subset of the space of symmetric/hermitian matricies something went wrong?

Comment: @Alpha001: Hermitian matrices are not always symmetric matrices. The dimensionality of the space of *symmetric* matrices is 6. For *Hermitian* matrices, it's 9.